# Pythonのロギング／ローテート設定を複数モジュールで使いたい

Tags: python, logging

Windows 10
Python 3.6

directory example

```
|-- main.py
|-- modules/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- funcs.py
`-- log/
    `-- root.log
```

---

複数モジュールからロギングする(main.pyからもfuncs.pyからもログを出したい)場合，
https://docs.python.jp/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules
の通りに行えば，問題なくログ出力ができます．

しかしローテートの方法をカスタマイズする場合，main.pyに
https://docs.python.jp/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-rotator-and-namer-to-customize-log-rotation-processing
のように記述し，ロガーにハンドラを与えたところ，main.pyからのログに対してはローテートのカスタマイズが適用されました．
このときfuncs.pyからのログに対しても同様のカスタマイズを適用したい場合，funcs.pyにはどのように記述すべきでしょうか(同じログファイル`/log/root.log`に出力したい)．
main.pyと全く同じように記述すると，`PermissionError: [WinError 32]`となります．

＋α
できれば`logging.config.fileConfig(...)`で設定を読み込めると，もっとプログラムがスッキリすると思うのですが，ローテートのカスタマイズを適用したい場合はやりようがないですかね？

---

main.py

```
import logging
import modules.funcs

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
trh = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(...)
trh.rotator = rotator   # rotatorは別途作成
logger.addHandler(trh)

logger.debug('rotate test')
```

funcs.py

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
# ここで何らかの設定/記述をする?

logger.debug('rotate test @funcs.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

`funcs.py`の方は何もしなくてもいいはずです。`funcs.py`で何かの設定をすると別のロガー・オブジェクトになるので、同じログファイルに出力しようとすると`PermissionError: [WinError 32]`になります。

・公式ドキュメント logging --- Python 用ロギング機能 [ロガーオブジェクト](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/logging.html#logger-objects)

> ロガーを直接インスタンス化することはできず、常にモジュール関数 logging.getLogger(name) を介してインスタンス化することに注意してください。同じ name で getLogger() を複数回呼び出すと、常に同じロガー・オブジェクトへの参照が返されます。
>
> name は foo.bar.baz のようにピリオドで分割された (ただし単なるプレーンな foo もありえます) 潜在的に階層的な値です。階層リスト中でより下位のロガーは、上位のロガーの子です。例えば、foo という名前を持つロガーがあるとき、foo.bar, foo.bar.baz, foo.bam という名前を持つロガーはすべて foo の子孫です。ロガー名の階層は Python パッケージ階層と類似していて、推奨される構築方法 `logging.getLogger(__name__)` を使用してロガーをモジュール単位で構成すれば、Python パッケージ階層と同一になります。これは、モジュールの中では `__name__` が Python パッケージ名前空間におけるモジュール名だからです。

Answer (score 0):

PermissionErrorがでてるということは, 複数のプロセスを実行しているのですね？

その場合は, 「[複数のプロセスからの単一ファイルへのログ記録](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)」で以下の手法が紹介されています

- [ネットワーク越しの logging イベントの送受信](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#network-logging)
- 別の方法として、 Queue と QueueHandler を使う方法

---

#### logging.config に関して

`logging.config` の `fileConfig`は, 設定ファイルを用意しておけば簡単に設定できるが

- JSON / YAML などで記述し(`load`して) `dictConfig`したほうが, 記述が分かりやすく便利に思える
- 標準の [ロギングハンドラー](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.handlers.html) (`RotatingFileHandler` や `TimedRotatingFileHandler` 程度)までなら簡単に利用できるが, カスタマイズしたハンドラーを扱い出すと面倒になりがち

という感じですね

---

でもまずは, カスタムロギングハンドラーをモジュール化して
各プログラム(各プロセス) で `import` し動作させることから始めたらいいのではないでしょうか？